# Non OnGUI based progress bar in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How can I make a progress bar appear in Unity that doesn't make use of the OnGUI functionality in C#?

I'm doing something with an Oculus and the OnGUI stuff doesn't work too well in a stereoscopic setting. I'm open to hear suggestions or try code samples as I can't seem to think of a way to display this in Unity and every google search brings up OnGUI examples.

Comment: So what are you using for your UI?

Comment: Planes in the 3D world at the moment. How the GUI system works doesn't translate to how the stereoscopic is set up, which is two cameras displaying half the the screen each. If I used the GUI system it would only render over 1 eye and cause a lot of pain to the user.

Comment: Then just do as @user2599140 says.

Answer (score 2):

Use a poly and resize it, or don't reinvent the wheel and use NGUI (which creates all necessary geometry and has code for all common widgets, including progress bars).